# Moving between mobile app pages securely and store user sensitive data credential

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library

I have **Xamarin.forms** written on pcl, how can i store user session so the user credential date are secured,i thought of having a boolean variable which is shared between pages and tell if the user logged in or not(a guest), but i am sure its static and not dynamic way and overall not secure , i searched the web but most of solutions were platform specific which means that i have to implement render on each platform, and the second issue is where to save username and password on the device if the user want to login again without providing username and password every time he/she wants to login 
overall my app is connected to web service online(wcf),i want all my coding goes on pcl nothing out..,sorry for my poor English

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Xam.Plugins.Settings library, you can find it in nuget:

[Xam.Plugins.Settings](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugins.Settings)

And you can follow this guide:

[James Montemagno SettingsPlugin](https://jamesmontemagno.github.io/SettingsPlugin/)